# A equation based on logarithms.

Tags: logarithms

So I've been trying to solve a question based on logarithms and it says this:-

> Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be real numbers, each greater than 1, such that $$\frac{2}{3}\log_{b}{a} + \frac{3}{5}\log_{c}{b} + \frac{5}{2}\log_{a}{c} = 3.$$
> If $b = 9$, then what is the value of $a$?

So far, after trying everything using elementary logarithmic operations, I arrived here:-

> $$\log_{b^3}{a^2} + \log_{c^5}{b^3} + \log_{a^2}{c^5} = 3$$

Now, I'm proposing that all of those logarithms to be equal to 1. But I'm not sure if that proposition holds true everywhere. I have tried to assume a real number $k > 1$ where $\log c^5 = k\log a^2$, and then try to see if that holds true for the relation given, but the expression which yields after that is not something pleasant.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Surely its coming out to be A.M. equal to G.M. that means all three no.s are equal so you can form three equations and find the answer.

Comment: Understood, so I have to use the base change law to get an equation like $$\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{a} = 3$$, which could be used to get the relation of AM-GM.

Comment: Yes, you got it right